# "Meet our team" is a click bait

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Please stop opening the jobs page of the company when I click on a username.
E.g. when clicking this one, my obvious intention is to "meet your team" (check the profile pages) and not to earn you referral money, nor to get to a generic company page:

[image]

(esp. given the fact that it is so easy to misleadingly use avatars of famous hackers to lure people to the bait)